# Pinpoint List View Item in Android

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I have been working on a certain project which involves the use of web service. I have a list of products that will display in UI as Image,Button to Like,Add To List and some other. I have implemented these items in a Custom ListView and added the products in the Adapter class as always. If I select a Like button for a certain image then the button should  change to Unlike, the problem that I am facing here is that the button changes for all the items i.e. all the buttons in the list view gets changed to Like which is idiotic.

**Question :**

How do I pinpoint a certain list item to get changed (or) How do I change a single button in a list ?

I am short of logic to be used here. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: do so in the adapter, i am sure you know well as to which item needs the like button and which needs the unlike button, then based on that condition set the buttons in the getView method of the adapter

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Thanks for the info though.

Answer (score 0):

Without code it is difficult to help specifically, but have you tried using something like,

```
listview.getChildAt(position);
```

to reference a particular list item.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your code, you can modify this:

```
yourlistview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long arg3) {

                //on click of any item.
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your position"+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //This is just for example to obtain the position of the listview item.
                TextView example= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sometext);
                example.setText(String.valueOf(position));

            }
        });
```

Hope this gives you some information..:)